# Finding Generating Function of Series, Coefficients Relate to Partitions

Tags: combinatorics, generating-functions, integer-partitions, combinatorial-proofs

Let $\displaystyle p_{\leq c}(n)$ represent the number of partitions of $n$ into at most $c$ parts. What is the generating function of $\displaystyle\sum_{n \geq 0} p_{\leq c}(n)x^n$?

I'm completely stumped by this problem, not even sure where to start. I know that if the coefficients were just the number of partitions of $n$ without restriction, then the generating function would be $\displaystyle\prod_{n=1}^\infty \dfrac{1}{1-x^n}$, but I don't know how to use this fact. I also suspect there's a relationship between $p_{\leq c}(n)$ and $p_{\leq c}(n-1)$, $p_{\leq c}(n-2)$, and so on that I can use, but I have no idea what.

Thanks!

Comment: The smartest idea I can come up with is to let $p_c(n)$ be the number of partitions of $n$ into exactly $c$ parts, and then sum $\sum_{k=1}^c p_k(n)$. For the partition function associated to $p_c(n)$, see page 3 [here](https://math.berkeley.edu/~mhaiman/math172-spring10/partitions.pdf). (I don't think this leads to a nice closed form for arbitrary $c$.)

Comment: Look back at the proof of the $\prod_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{1-x^n}$ formula. Use the fact that the number of partitions of $n$ into at most $c$ parts is the same as the number of partitions of $n$ with parts of size at most $c$.

Comment: @JoshuaP.Swanson Thank you! I completely forgot about that fact.